# How to call Python script with arguments from C++, using exec syscall

Tags: python, c++, unix, system-calls

I want to call python script from C++ program as a child process.

I want to run this command: `/home/minty99/.virtualenvs/venv_waveglow/bin/python /home/minty99/tacotron2/inference.py mps 1 4`

which have commandline argument for python.

I tried these code:

`string pt_arg = "mps " + to_string(i) + " " + to_string(fd[i][1]);`

[1] `execl("bash", "-c", "/home/minty99/.virtualenvs/venv_waveglow/bin/python /home/minty99/tacotron2/inference.py", pt_arg.c_str(), NULL);`

[2] `execl("/home/minty99/.virtualenvs/venv_waveglow/bin/python", "/home/minty99/tacotron2/inference.py", pt_arg.c_str(), NULL);`

But it was not working.

> First one: exec fails with "No such file or directory"
>
> Second one: /home/minty99/tacotron2/inference.py: can't open file 'mps
>   1 4': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but reading the manpage of execl, it says

> The first argument, by convention, should point to the file name
>        associated with the file being executed.

Where

> int
>        execl(const char *file, const char *arg0, ... /*, (char *)0 */);

To me, this means your second version should likely read

```
execl("/home/minty99/.virtualenvs/venv_waveglow/bin/python", "python", "/home/minty99/tacotron2/inference.py", pt_arg.c_str(), NULL);
```

Which makes sense, since if you get the list of arguments in python, `sys.argv[0]` will be "python", not your first argument.